# Getting KitKat on my Galaxy S4

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-4, 4.4-kitkat, samsung

I was wondering if there was like an installation that you can install to a Galaxy S4 device to enable you to get KitKat?
I know some people with Galaxy S4's have already got KitKat installed, but it is taking forever to come through as a software update.

Do Samsung push out the KitKat update or the mobile carrier?

Comment: This may sound stupid but have you tried the "check for update" button (located in settings)

Comment: I have tried that, on 4G and Wi-Fi, but the update does not get pushed through

Comment: Officially: not yet, give it a few weeks. Even if your network/device is getting it they usually stagger it by IMEI so someone may have it and not you. As of now only Korea and certain US carriers have an official release. Unofficial: there is the samsung leak of it, there is the Google Edition ROMS that have been around for a few months. Check out XDA. The CARRIER roll it out. It is sent from Samsung > Carrier > Handset!

Answer (score 2):

I'm O2 UK as well, and at 4.3, my phone is 'up to date'.

[This article](http://www.androidpit.com/kitkat-update-samsung-phones) suggests we'll be getting Kitkat, but not quite yet. If you look at comparable previous releases from Samsung, I think we've still got months yet.

Comment: Apologies for the late response.
That is exactly what mine says - very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, updates generally come through the carrier. Each carrier has to test & approve the update; so if an AT&T S4 has the 4.4 update, that doesn't mean that the Verizon version has been approved.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I am on O2-UK, but other people in the UK with S4's have had the update pushed out, but not sure if it is worth updating manually instead of waiting for the update to be pushed over.